# Даны действительные числа a0, . . . , a6. Получить для x = 1, 3, 4 значения p(x + 1) − p(x), где p(y) = a6y 6 + a5y 5 + · · · + a0

Tags: c

Даны действительные числа a0, . . . , a6. Получить для x = 1, 3, 4 значения p(x + 1) − p(x), где p(y) = a6y
6 + a5y
5 + · · · + a0.

Куча ошибок в коде. Я уже отчаялся, от того факта, что ничего не получается

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double p(double y);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int i;
double a[7];
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);

for (i=1; i<4; i++){
if (i!=2)
printf("%lf\n", p(i+1) - p(i));
}

return 0;
}

double p(double y){ 
return a[0] + a[1]*y + a[2]*pow(y ,2) + a[3]*pow(y ,3) + a[4]*pow(y ,4) + 
a[5]*pow(y ,5) + a[6]*pow(y ,6);
}
```

Comment: Что за дикая идея при каждом вызове функции `p()` запрашивать у пользователя значения `a[]`??? Зачем? Почему?

Comment: Других вариантов я не нашел. Можете лучше - напишите

Comment: Как это "не нашел"? У вас в функции `main` явно виден закомментированный вполне уместный единократный ввод `a[]`. Почему он вдруг оказался закомментирован и перекочевал внутрь `p()`? Зачем вы это сделали?

Comment: Ладно, исправил. Что дальше?

Comment: @Deadler Что-то мне не нравится тон Вашего последнего комментария.

Answer (score 1):

Вы почему-то не передаете в `p()` массив `a`. Собственно, это главная ошибка.

Не ошибка, но некрасиво - вы не используете схему Горнера при вычислении `p()`.

Попробуйте так:

```
double p(double y, double a[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    double a[7];

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        scanf("%lf", &a[i]);

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (i != 2)
            printf("%lf\n", p(i + 1, a) - p(i, a));
        }

    return 0;
    }

double p(double y, double a[]) {
    double res = 0.0;

    for (int i = 6; i > 0; --i)
        res = res * y + a[i];

    return res;
    }
```

Второй вариант - сделать массив `a` глобальным, но применение глобальных переменных - плохой способ решения проблем, не нужно к нему привыкать...

Comment: Раз для "1, 3, 4" - то цикл должен быть `for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)`.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, исправил.